# How to get the current page URL and use it

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to deploy a project on the Cloud, I need to get the current url of the page, change it and use it.
Example: 
the current url: 123.123.123.123:8080/home
and I want to href to 123.123.123.123:8082/add

I want to use a Javascript function to generate "http://localhost:8083/businesss" and use it ..

Comment: @dippas This is not a duplicate of what you linked to.

Comment: What, ultimately, are you going to do with this manipulated url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to manipulate a URL is to first get it into its parsed form.  Use `URL` for this:

```
const url = new URL(location.href);
```

On that URL object are two properties you're interested in.  The first is `host`, which specifies the hostname and port number.  In your example, your first URL would have the `host` set to `123.123.123.123:8080`.  You could change this to `123.123.123.123:8082` like so:

```
url.host = '123.123.123.123:8082';
```

Then to get the string form of the URL:

```
url.toString(); // http://123.123.123.123:8082/home
```

The next property you want to manipulate is `pathname`, and it works the same way.  Just modify that to change the path, and use the `url` as a string to get the string version.

Also, unrelated to your question, but please consider using the designated documentation IP addresses in your questions in the future.  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737  You never know when you might use an example address that might actually be in use by someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
 window.location.href
```

will return to the you the current url of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `window.location.href`. [Explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

You can then put `window.location.href = "http://localhost:8083/businesss"` or whatever href you need.